# management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=* in production

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-actuator

Small question regarding Spring Actuator and the property `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` please.

It is well known, seen in many tutorial, docs, online video, etc, this property `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` should not be enabled with `*` in production. I remember seeing many "do not do this in production".

My question is, while it is clear this should not be done in prod, what would be the best setting please?

I understand the "well, it depends on your needs, you should configure this based on your use case, etc" but may I ask, what are the no-no endpoints to be enabled in prod? What are those who can stay?

Thank you